# How to locate a webtable cell with specific text in selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium

I have trouble in locating a webtable with a specific text in cell in selenium using c#

As the following Html

```
<td class="status">
  <Span class="label label-status"> new <span>
<td>
```

I need to locate with the text "new" so if this condition pass click on this cell

Comment: Could you provide the HTML code of the element you are trying to call? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to be able to call the element with xpath:

```
//Span[contains(text(), 'new')] (assuming Span is with capital letter which is unlikely)
```

or

```
//span[contains(text(), 'new')]
```

If there are multiple span elements with text 'new' in it, you can try:

```
//td[@class='status']/span[contains(text(), 'new')]
```